# Ruby on rails application helper not working in index view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am newbie in ruby on rails and I am starting to love it. I just spotted a problem about using helper in my views. I just can't see the link I have created in my helper to my index view but I can see the link from other views. What is the problem with this? Please help. Thanks a lot. Here are my codes

Application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper


def main_menu
    link_to("Go to Main Menu", {controller: 'access', action: 'index'})
end


end
```

index.html.erb (helper not working here)

```
<% @page_title = "Admin users" %>
<%= main_menu() %>
<div class="admin_user index">
<h2>Admin Users</h2>
</div>
```

Output:
[image]

edit.html.erb (helper works here)

```
<%= main_menu() %>
<div class="edit user">
<h1>Edit user form</h1>
 </div>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Can you also include your routes.rb?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code sample works just fine for me. There is nothing inherently wrong with your `ApplicationHelper`. What controller does your index and edit action belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

This helper method will find the path by `controller` and `action` if it exists:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # @note `return`s below are for illustration but not required
  # @see https://github.com/rails/journey
  def link(txt, ctl, act)
    begin
      x = Rails.application.routes.routes.select {|x| x.defaults[:controller] == ctl and x.defaults[:action] == act}.first.path.spec.left.to_s

      return link_to(txt.html_safe, x)
    rescue => e
      message = "ERROR route does not exist; controller: #{ctl}, action: #{act}; #{e.message}"

      # log
      Rails.logger.error(message)

      # raise (not graceful)
      raise message

      # or return (graceful)
      return nil
    end
  end

end


# in the view
link('dude&nbsp;awesome', 'controller_name', 'action_name')
#=> <a href="/controller/action_name">dude&nbsp;awesome</a>
```

Using the above method, you could modify you `application_helper.rb` like this:

```
def main_menu
  link("Go to Main Menu", 'access', 'index')
end
```

Parens `()` on the method are not required… try this syntax and see if you like it:

```
<%= main_menu %>
```